# Why won't gradle Exec task run my command?

Tags: gradle

I have read around stackoverflow and the gradle forms, but I am still stumped.  The ultimate goal here is that after I copy some files, I want to set the writable flag -- because 'copy' doesn't like overwriting read-only files on 'nix (huh...), nor can it be forced to do so (harumph!).

Here is the outline of what I have:

```
task setPermissions (type : Exec) {
  executable = 'chmod -R +w'
}

// ... a little while later ...

task('somethingElse') << {
  // ... unrelated stuff ...
  def String targetDir = "$aVar/theTarget"

  // >> TASK CALL <<
  setPermissions {
    commandLine = [executable + " $targetDir"]
  }

  // but that doesn't work... this does...
  proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R +w $deployDir")
  proc.waitFor()

}
```

I have tried variations in "setPermissions".

**Trial 1:**

```
commandLine = 'chmod'
args = '-R', '+w'
```

In which case I appended the target directory to "args" when I called setPermissions.

**Trial 2:**

```
commandLine = 'chmod -R +w'
```

In which case I appended the target directory to "commandLine" when I called setPermissions.  I also tried making it the only "args" value.

**Trial 3:**

```
commandLine = 'chmod', '-R', '+w'
```

In which case I appended the target directory to "commandLine" when I called setPermissions.  I also tried making it the only "args" value.

So what am I doing wrong here that an Exec task won't run this properly, but the Rt.gR.exec() will?

Answer (score 4):

You can't call a task from another task. You'll have to make one depend on the other, or call the [Project.exec](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3aexec%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) *method* from a task action. The syntax for configuring the `exec` method is exactly the same as for the `Exec` task.

PS: Have you tried to use [Copy.fileMode](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy%3afileMode) instead of `chmod`?

Comment: Peter, thank you.  I'll take a look into Project.exec.  I read up on Copy.fileMode.  My understanding is that it is more like saying "chmod 755" as apposed to "+w".  All I want to do is enable 'write' on all files, not tamper with read or execute.  Am I misunderstanding how fileMode works?

Comment: If you want to do `+w`, you can't use `fileMode`. I'd check if there is an Ant task for that.