# android: gradle: how to copy a file? Issue to set a file readable, or to read it

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, chmod

I am blocked by a file reading in Gradle.

I try to set files readable this way in gradle:

```
task readAccess(type: Exec, description: 'set the google-services.json readable.') {
     //--> check can read? --> can't read
    if (new File('src/google-services.json').canRead()){
        println 'readAccess > can read'
    } else {
        println 'readAccess > cant read'
    }
    //--> set readable. --> can't set readable
    if (new File('src/google-services.json').setReadable(true,false)) {
        println 'readAccess > access read modified'
    } else {
        println 'readAccess > access read not modified'
    }
    //--> check can read? --> can't read
    if (new File('src/google-services.json').canRead()){
        println 'readAccess > can read'
    } else {
        println 'readAccess > cant read'
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn gcmReadAccess
}
```

PS: the file access is set to read & write by everyone, in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

find my solution to my real problem: **how to copy a file with gradle?** . I was going in the wrong way.

```
copy {
  from 'src/'
            include '*.json'
            into '..'
}
```

You can find more details in [enter link description here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3Aexec%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628235/why-wont-gradle-exec-task-run-my-command) , even if it's not too related to my question, but helped me.